# Error running chef libraries

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using chef-solo to test my recipes. I am trying to use  library to trigger an email. Here is what i have done.

Created a libraries directory in my cookbooks directory

```
cat /tmp/chefrepo/cookbooks/poc/libraries/helper.rb
require 'net/smtp'

module HandlerSendEmail
  class Helper

    def send_email_on_run_failure(node_name)

      message = "From: Chef <chef@chef.io>\n"
      message << "To: Grant <grantmc@chef.io>\n"
      message << "Subject: Chef run failed\n"
      message << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
      message << "Chef run failed on #{node_name}\n"
      Net::SMTP.start('localhost', 25) do |smtp|
        smtp.send_message message, 'chef@chef.io', 'grantmc@chef.io'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And a simple recipe

```
cat /tmp/chefrepo/cookbooks/poc/recipes/default.rb
#
# Cookbook:: poc
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2017, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.
ruby_block 'fail the run' do
  block do
    fail 'deliberately fail the run'
  end
end

Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_failed do
    HandlerSendEmail::Helper.new.send_email_on_run_failure(
      Chef.run_context.node.name
    )
  end
end
```

When I run chef solo using `chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json`
I get

```
Running handlers:
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] ERROR: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Chef::Recipe:0x0000000004875ee8>>::HandlerSendEmail
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] ERROR: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Chef::Recipe:0x0000000004875ee8>>::HandlerSendEmail
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[2017-09-29T12:49:09+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Anything I am missing? I tried changing libraries directory location at the same level as that of cookbooks directory but it did not work.

Comment: Does it work if you make that `::HandlerSendEmail::Helper.new....`?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the commands to mixin your helper resource. At the bottom of your library file add the following

`Chef::Recipe.include(HelperSendEmail)
Chef::Resource.include(HelperSendEmail)`

This will make your resource available.

Source:https://www.sidorenko.io/post/2016/10/writing-helper-cookbooks-with-shared-functions/

Comment: This is unrelated to the issue.